# while reading from the text file is finding extra character (ex.'@') even if it is not there?

Tags: c++

Here is my code: In this case I am getting '@' which is conflicting with the the '@' in the file

```
  ifstream file("text.dat");
    if(file.is_open()){
    bool flag=false;
```

here I am getting a extra character

```
getline(file,str,'\n');}
```

Here is the text file, I am reading from this text file!

jim Workshop 5 is cool
harry @jim working on workshop 5 now 
chris
dave what the ^#$%!
john @harry I'm done

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here.It's specially important to post a [mcve].

Comment: your file contains the @ character..... this is the line involved "harry @jim working on workshop 5 now"

Comment: Thank you to look at my problem. I can understand that the line has the character but the index of the character is 1234567895522!!! why???

Answer (score 5):

[std::string::find()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) returns `std::string::npos` if the character is not found, and `std::string::npos` is a constant representing max size of a string. It is the huge number that you see.

Your `if` statements should look like this:

```
if(std.find('@') != std::string::npos)
{
    //blabla
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Look at the output of your program:

> '@' is here!!!!: 18446744073709551615

`18446744073709551615` is the value that `str.find("@")` is returning.  `find()` returns the *index* of the substring if found, otherwise it returns `std::string::npos`, which is defined as `-1` casted to `std::string::size_type`, which is an *unsigned* type.  In this case, `size_type` is a 64bit number, and so you end up with index `18446744073709551615` when `npos` is returned.

Any non-zero value will evaluate as true in a boolean expression, such as an `if` statement.  That is why you end up setting `flag=true`.  This is a bug in your code for two reasons:

- you are evaluating to true when `find()` does not find a match at all.
- you are evaluating to false when `find()` finds a match at position 0 (the 1st character of the string).

You need to change this:

```
if(str.find("@")) flag=true;
```

To this instead:

```
if(str.find("@") != string::npos) flag=true;
```

Or simply this:

```
flag = (str.find("@") != string::npos);
```

Answer (score 3):

`std::string::find()` returns `std::string::npos` if it fails to find the needle, the value of `npos` is -1, which is coerced to the boolean true, not false.

You need to compare the result of `find()` to `npos` directly, instead of doing the implicit coercion.